Player score remains zero in rock, paper, scissors
I have this implementation of rock, paper, scissors, where I use buttons with images for the user to indicate their choice.
But the player score won't go up -- it remains 0, no matter what. The computer score works just fine. I only have trouble with getting the player score right. What am I doing wrong?


let result;
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let playerSelection;
const buttonBox = document.querySelector(".selections");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const roundsBox = document.querySelector(".rounds");
const selection = ["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"];
const pScore = document.querySelector("#playerScore");
const cScore = document.querySelector("#compScore");

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playerSelection = selection.data-selection;
    playRound(computerSelection());
    game();
  });
});

const computerSelection = function () {
  return selection[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
};

function playRound(computerSelection) {
  const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  const oneRound = document.createElement("div");
  oneRound.classList.add("oneRound");
  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    h1.textContent = "DRAW";
  } else if (playerSelection == "ROCK" && computerSelection == "SCISSORS") {
    h1.textContent = "WIN";
    playerScore += 1;
  } else if (playerSelection == "PAPER" && computerSelection == "ROCK") {
    h1.textContent = "WIN";
    playerScore += 1;
  } else if (playerSelection == "SCISSORS" && computerSelection == "PAPER") {
    h1.textContent = "WIN";
    playerScore += 1;
  } else {
    h1.textContent = "LOSE";
    computerScore += 1;
  }
  
  pScore.textContent = playerScore;
  cScore.textContent = computerScore;
}

function game() {
  const finalResult = document.createElement("div");
  finalResult.classList.add("rounds");
  if (playerScore != 5 && computerScore != 5) {
    return
  } else if (playerScore == 5) {
    finalResult.textContent = "YOU WON! :D";
  } else if (computerScore == 5) {
    finalResult.textContent = "YOU LOST! :(";
  }
  roundsBox.prepend(finalResult);
  buttonBox.replaceWith(finalResult);
}
<div class='selections'>
    <button class='selection' data-selection='rock'> <img alt="rock" src='images/rock.png'> </button>
    <button class='selection' data-selection='paper'> <img alt="paper"  src='images/paper.png'> </button>
    <button class='selection' data-selection='scissors'> <img alt="scissors"  src='images/scissors.png'> </button>
</div>
<div class='results'>
    <div>
        <pre><h1>Player <span id="playerScore">0</span> - <span id="compScore">0</span> Computer</h1></pre>
        <div class="rounds">First to 5 wins!</div>
    </div>
</div>




There might be a type mismatch in else if conditions. Can you make sure that the else if condition is true, for example:
else if (playerSelection == "ROCK" && computerSelection == "SCISSORS") {
    console.log("something")
    h1.textContent = "WIN";
    playerScore += 1;
  }

and check your console if it prints

There are several reasons why the player's score does not increase:

selection is an array, so selection.data-selection is not accessing the chosen button. You need to reference button somewhere...

If we fix the previous issue with button.selection.data-selection, then still it does not select the button's data-selection property, but selects the data property (which is undefined) and subtracts selection from it (as a arithmetic operation). This is of course not what you wanted to happen. Do access that data property, use button.dataset.selection.

That data property has the choices in lowercase (like "rock"), while the computer moves are in capitals. So that breaks your logic of determining the outcome. You can either update those data properties to upppercase or call toUpperCase.


So a fix would be to change this stateme:
playerSelection = button.selection.data-selection;

to this statement:
playerSelection = button.dataset.selection.toUpperCase();

Check it out:


let result;
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let playerSelection;
const buttonBox = document.querySelector(".selections");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const roundsBox = document.querySelector(".rounds");
const selection = ["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"];
const pScore = document.querySelector("#playerScore");
const cScore = document.querySelector("#compScore");

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playerSelection = button.dataset.selection.toUpperCase();
    playRound(computerSelection());
    game();
  });
});

const computerSelection = function () {
  return selection[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
};

function playRound(computerSelection) {
  const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  const oneRound = document.createElement("div");
  oneRound.classList.add("oneRound");
  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    h1.textContent = "DRAW";
  } else if (playerSelection == "ROCK" && computerSelection == "SCISSORS") {
    h1.textContent = "WIN";
    playerScore += 1;
  } else if (playerSelection == "PAPER" && computerSelection == "ROCK") {
    h1.textContent = "WIN";
    playerScore += 1;
  } else if (playerSelection == "SCISSORS" && computerSelection == "PAPER") {
    h1.textContent = "WIN";
    playerScore += 1;
  } else {
    h1.textContent = "LOSE";
    computerScore += 1;
  }
  
  pScore.textContent = playerScore;
  cScore.textContent = computerScore;
}

function game() {
  const finalResult = document.createElement("div");
  finalResult.classList.add("rounds");
  if (playerScore != 5 && computerScore != 5) {
    return
  } else if (playerScore == 5) {
    finalResult.textContent = "YOU WON! :D";
  } else if (computerScore == 5) {
    finalResult.textContent = "YOU LOST! :(";
  }
  roundsBox.prepend(finalResult);
  buttonBox.replaceWith(finalResult);
}
<div class='selections'>
    <button class='selection' data-selection='rock'> <img alt="rock" src='images/rock.png'> </button>
    <button class='selection' data-selection='paper'> <img alt="paper"  src='images/paper.png'> </button>
    <button class='selection' data-selection='scissors'> <img alt="scissors"  src='images/scissors.png'> </button>
</div>
<div class='results'>
    <div>
        <pre><h1>Player <span id="playerScore">0</span> - <span id="compScore">0</span> Computer</h1></pre>
        <div class="rounds">First to 5 wins!</div>
    </div>
</div>




I would also add that an IDE should be able to point out a few of those problems, such as that selection.data is undefined and that subtracting by an array is probably wrong.
Side note: I just found some interesting behaviour: 9 - [5] yields 4, but 5 - [1, 2] yields NaN (I'm surprised the first case worked).

@Christian, when you subtract an array, the array gets coerced to string, then the string gets coerced to number. So [5] coerces via "5" to 5, but [1,2] coerces via "1,2" to NaN.

and I thought PHP was the crazy one.
